# Wordpress constant redirect with nginx upstream

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx

A situation has come up where server1, running Nginx, will forward all "/" locations to server2, while keeping "/api" and a few others on server1. This is also trying to keep SSL working. Trying to move the WP url from http://test.example.com to https://example.com has the front page load properly, but loading `wp-admin` gives too many redirects.

Server1 Nginx:

```
upstream webapp_url {
    server IP:80;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location /files/ {
                root /home;
                access_log off;
                expires max;
                if ($request_filename !~* ^.*?\.(jpg)|(png)|(gif)|(pdf)){
                        add_header Content-Disposition: "$request_filename";
                }
        }

        location / {
                # proxy_pass http://site_url/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Example "1";
                proxy_pass http://webapp_url/;
        }
```

This loads the other server fine, homepage and links all work (though mixed content warnings because I'm unable to change it in the admin). WP `siteurl` and `home` are both set to the new address.

Server2 Nginx:

```
server {
    #listen       443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com test.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
    error_log /var/log/wordpress/error.log info;
    location / {
        root   /home/wordpress;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    #ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/wordpress;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Loading `/wp-admin/` starts an infinite redirect (to the same url). I've defined it in `wp-config.php` too:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp-admin` checks to see if the connection is secure, otherwise it redirects to the `https` version of the same URL. In a situation such as yours, this causes a redirect loop.

You need to tell WordPress that the connection is secure.

I notice that you set the appropriate header on server 1 with:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

(In your case, the value of `$scheme` is hard-wired to `https`).

However, you also need to pass this to WordPress, in the form of an `HTTPS` parameter, with a value of `on`.

This is achieved with a `map` directive (on Server 2):

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $https_flag {
    default off;
    https on;
}
server {
    ...
}
```

(The `map` directive is placed within the `http` block. You can place it just above the `server` block as shown above. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details)

In addition, add another `fastcgi_param` to pass the `HTTPS` parameter to WordPress (on Server 2):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https_flag;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

- Enable and install your required PHP version on your server.

Step 2.

- `sudo yum install php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-mysqlnd`

Step 3.

- `sudo systemctl start php-fpm`

Step 4.

- `sudo systemctl enable php-fpm`

Finally copy Nginx configuration

```
server {
    root /path/to/your/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    location ~ .php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; # path might differ from OS to OS
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```